# Facebook login permissions for score

Tags: facebook, permissions, unity-game-engine

It's not clear to me how the permissions work in facebook.
I want to store the users highscore, and show a toplist with the user's friends scores.
I don't want to post on the feed of the user, I just want to use the scores api.

Do I need the publish_actions permission for that?

I've been creating test users for trying things out, and I noticed that the auth tokens have different scopes:

test user1: public_profile, basic_info, user_friends

test user2: public_profile, basic_info, publish_actions, user_friends

How the heck did test user2 get that permission?

I have a facebook app set up already, but if I needed the extra publish_actions permission, I would have to go trough a review process, right?

edit: 
my app is a unity3d game, running on android.
also it seems, that I can get read scores, but can not set a new score, I get an error on that.

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://graph.facebook.com/lotsofnumbers/scores
```

Answer (score 0):

according to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/scores#create-update-scores you'll need the `publish-actions` permission to be able to post a score.

"test user 2" can deny the permission (because it is extended) during the login flow, so I think this is ok.